# Streaming data from a single Kinesis Stream to multiple tables in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have data coming into Kinesis streams from different producers. The data needs to be transformed into several different tables depending the the they type of that data. I'm trying to have a Lambda read from Kinesis Streams, transform the data into the different tables and then use Kinesis Firehose to batch and COPY into Redshift.

However since Firehose can only deliver to one Redhsift table at a time, I need to have multiple Firehose instances running equal to the number of tables I will have in my Redshift schema. I see that there is a default cap of 20 Firehose instances per region and I'm wondering if this is an ideal data pipeline for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you use a Kinesis Analystics Application to do the pre-processing of the stream and split it into multiple streams?  It looks like you can make the destination streams a Kinesis Firehose to Redshift http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/app-tworecordtypes.html

Comment: @Nathan - Thanks for suggesting thing. While this is interesting, this does not solve the problem of using multiple instances of Kinesis Firehose - I'll still need as many Firehose instances as the number of tables in schema. Secondly, my data transformation is better suited to be written in python/javascript compared to raw sql since it I can use third party libraries to do some of the complex transforms.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a way of populating multiple Redshift tables from a single stream without either loading the original stream into a stage table first and then splitting it in Redshift, or splitting the stream and having one stream per table. Is Redshift a requirement? If not maybe Athena is an alternative?

Comment: Athena looks interesting. Will have to evaluate it. Our read query load will be intensive and relational (i.e involve JOINs though even having a flattened, de-normalized schema). We already use Redshift for some of our other analytics related services. Will have to evaluate Athena viz a viz Redshift for our use case.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths how can this be achieved with Athena? can you provide a documentation link maybe?

Comment: @MelihYıldız' This question is from nearly 5 years ago and I don't work with these tools any more so I don't think I can give a useful answer as things may have changed substantially since I originally commented.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths thanks. Just for the record I solved this by directing the event to a lambda first instead and then generating multiple Kinesis FH events inside the lambda by splitting the event's data. then the Kinesis FH transformer lambda does its magic on individual records

Answer (score 1):

I have designed almost similar data pipeline like yours. I get the data from the kinesis, transform the data after it has reached redshift. All the data from 1 stream goes to a one master table in redshift.Then, I run a cron job, which transforms the data into different tables. 
 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: How do you run this cron job? From what I understand there are limitations and overheads to running scheduled SQL scripts on Redshift or within AWS  in general. More things to manage like Cloudwatch and SQS/SNS or an EB instance. Also I do want to use the COPY command to batch and load data into Redshift, since doing batched bulk INSERTs is sub optimal. I will also have to flatten my structured data to almost unstructured data to create this one single table that can store it all.